# How to display a custom post type and all it's posts?

Tags: php, loops

I've created a custom post type for classes at a gym. I have a page called classes which has a title and a brief description.

I would like to display the custom post type below it. I would like to display all posts within the custom post type.

This is the layout I would like:

Title - Classes
Brief Text.

Custom Post type post - title

custom post type post - text

Custom post type post - title

custom post type post - text

At the moment I'm using the following:

```
 <?php query_posts( 'post_type=Beaudesert-Class'); ?>
  <?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php if ( is_front_page() ) { ?>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <?php } ?>
```

This only displays one of the posts and I can no longer display the title and the content of the classes page.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you have a syntax error when you try looping over the posts. Depending on how you've written your code, `the_post` needs to be checked if it is the front page.

```
<?php 
query_posts('post_type=Beaudesert-Class');
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post ){
    if ( is_front_page(the_post) ) { 
    }
    else { 
    }
  }
?>
```

Also do let us know what error message you are getting with your current code.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I'm not getting any error at the moment